# excel cell need data in spreadsheet cell display, but excel uses other data displayed in input box only

Tags: excel

I copied data from a callmanager. i want to use the data it displays in the spreadsheet which is hh:mm:ss. But in the input box in the top it shows other data (date and time which i think display the date and time of recording of the data). When I try to use to manipulate the hh:mm:ss in the spreadsheet it keeps using the data in te input box. How can I tell excel to use the data displayed in the spread sheet and remove the data in the input box?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a specific method to do it in excel only, but what I've been using so far for instances like this is:

1. Copy the column having those values and paste into notepad,
2. Insert a new column in the worksheet and format it as `Text`,
3. Copy everything from the notepad and paste into that new column.

This might be a little awkward, but it works for me ^_^

Comment: Hmmm if all else fails I think theres nothing left but to try this. problem is the amount of data is quite large so I'm hoping for a quicker and more automated answer. but thanks anyway!

Comment: misread your answer! thought i had to delete all the extra data in every cell, but it works like a charm! thx!

Comment: @LennartWijers Thanks! If I find a workaround, I'll let you know! I often deal with badly formatted dates (American and British dates together and when they get mixed in excel, it's not always pretty) and I'm looking for a better solution as well.