# Excel 2010: Hours and Minutes extract from hh:mm:ss formatted cell

Tags: excel, time

For example:

I have a cell with the following value:

"1/11/1900  4:00:20 AM"

that will be displayed inside the cell as: "268:00:20" - meaning 268 hours, 00 minutes and 20 seconds (see the first image below).

EDIT:
Here is screen of how it looks like and the formatting of the cell [image: Cell with data]

Here comes the Question:

**What is the Excel 2010 formula (no VBA if possible!) *to extract hours* and *to extract minutes* from this cell**, such as "268" should be shown for hours in a different cell and "00" (in this case) for minutes in another cell?

For clarification: the "268:00:20" is a duration of 268 hours and 00 minutes and 20 seconds.

What I'd like to get? In different cells, store the hours (268) and minutes (0)

The cell is formatted as Time (see the image below): 
[image: Excel 2010 - Time Format Cell]

Comment: Have you checked: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/hour-HP005209115.aspx

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin That would return 4, the hours of the time portion only. He also needs the number of days represented as hours added to it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The value 1/11/1900 4:00:20 AM is really only a formatted number in Excel representing the number of days, i.e approx 11.167 in this case - I think Daniel's solution is not far off - using DAY and HOUR will work for values up to 31 days.......but for a more generic solution for hours use just:

`=INT(A1*24)`

and for minutes

`=MINUTE(A1)`

Answer (score 2):

I would use something similar to what I used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15953224/1578604). It's not really pretty for a solution but it works.

So, in your case what you do is:

1. Format the values in the time you want to, and copy/paste the value
   (or column) into notepad. The clipboard copies and pastes what's visible
   instead of the date/time value in excel.
2. In your worksheet, insert a
   new column and format it as text. This will cause excel to accept
   the values as is and not convert them into date time.
3. Copy everything from notepad and paste into the new column you just
   formatted as text. You will get the values of the time as is in
   excel.

From there, you can use a `Text to column` with colon delimited to split the time to get 3 columns: hours, minutes and seconds (and additional tip, in the split to column window, where you are asked about the format of the split columns, format all as text).

[image]

EDIT: Since it doesn't seem too obvious...

[image]

- Column B is the original date/time.
- Column C is the same date/time
  formatted in hours, minutes and seconds only. Copy and paste column C
  in notepad.
- Format Column D as text, then copy the values in notepad
  to the column. This gives you the time stored as text.
- Column E to G is the split of column D, colon delimited.

Comment: This would not work [Text to Columns](http://i.imgur.com/es58vJl.png) would give me this. Make sure you format the source cell as described!

Comment: @PinkSheep Did you first generate the text format of the time in hours, minutes and seconds? From your screenshot, it doesn't seem so. You then need to pick 'Delimited' and not 'Fixed Width' in the first step. I added another picture and description to make it clearer.

Comment: @Jerry All this is not needed please see my answer for the only answer that should be here.

Comment: @user2140261 I'm not sure it's so simple, because it seems the OP already knows how to display as hh:mm:ss because the format `Number > Time > 37:30:55` already does this in the OP. I'll wait for the OP's response, if they ever come back to reply.

Comment: @Jerry I see this an _interesting_ workaround but it does not automate anything :( I hope I'll find a better solution!

Comment: @PinkSheep Okay, I'm glad you managed to understand how this works. I'm still looking for how to work with 'Displayed' values in excel and 'Actual' values since I need to work with dates almost all the time and I use this method in the worst cases. At least, it gets the job done. Good luck in finding the solution!

Comment: @PinkSheep - did you see my suggestion - for hours you can use simply =INT(A1*24) where A1 contains your value.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `Day` and `Hour` formulas.
The Hours will return only the time part.
You will have to sum it with `24*Day`. Maybe you will need to use `Year` as well, depending on what you want.

For the minutes, use `Minute`formula.

If there's a start date and the desired date, you can use `24 * Days(DesiredDate, StartDate)`.

Comment: the `Day()` function only returns the Day of the month by itself not anything of value to him.

Comment: As months and years don't always have the same amount of hours this will still not become a simple formula.

Comment: Then use `Days` and put the date you want together with de first date you consider as zero. Because that will bring a time `interval`.

Comment: @Daniel - yes, 24*DAY(A1)+HOUR(A1) will give you 268 in this case.......but that solution only works up to 31 days (because DAY gives day of month) and it could also fall down if you use 1904 date system - a simpler solution is too use =INT(A1*24), see my answer - which works in all cases

Comment: ....but DAYS would require two dates, my understanding is that there's a single value. Also DAYS function isn't available in Excel 2010 - it's new in Excel 2013

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any formulas at all. Just format the cell with this format `[h]:mm:ss;@`

Example below:

Say your date is in Cell A1 as shown:

[image]

Go to format options:

[image]

Then Under the `Number` Tab Select Custom. Then enter the above Custom time format into the box:

[image]

And your cell will end up as:

[image]

Or by formula you could do it using `DateDif()` with the formula `=DATEDIF(0,A1,"D")*24+HOUR(A1)&":"&MINUTE(A1)&":"&SECOND(A1)`

as shown below:

[image]

Comment: This won't be formatted as time and is stored as plain text.  It won't let you do any calculations that require a Date type.

Comment: @Jesse The question says `that will be display inside the cell as: "268:00:20"` There is NO way to format that as a time. Excel will not recognize anything over 24 hours as a time.

Comment: @Jesse I was wrong and I completely over complicated the solution I have updated my answer accordingly

Comment: I wasn't suggesting it wasn't a solution, just that it had limitations depending on what the asker wanted to do with the info after that.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Text To Column function under Data in the Menu Bar. Works really well for time that is more than 24 hours. I had a problem where the minutes and seconds were displayed inconsistently sometimes in 2 digits and sometimes in 1 digit eg. 268:1:13 or 541:12:3 or 671:45:30. In that case just select delimiter as ":" (vs Fixed Width option) and it will be able to display the Hours Minutes and Seconds in separate columns. Problem Solved!